# Facebook Open Graph Using Spring Social

Tags: facebook-opengraph, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to create a web application for facebook and I want to have the possibility to publish different actions. To create the app I'm using Spring Social Facebook API binding which has a method of OpenGraphOperation interface that should publish actions: `publishAction(java.lang.String action, java.lang.String objectType, java.lang.String objectUrl).`
I am unclear on how and what I should define as `objectUrl`, and how to create a specific object in my application?
I saw that there is another question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336842/open-graph-publish-using-spring-social) similar but without a solution

Regards,

Comment: What actions are we talking about here?

Answer (score 0):

The object of the action is the target of the action and therefore objectUrl locates that object.

If you want to create an action representing someone rating a book then in the context of

```
publishAction(java.lang.String action, java.lang.String objectType, java.lang.String objectUrl)
```

you might have for example action=rate_that_book, objectType=book and objectUrl=http://safaribooks.com/123lkj123lk12j3

Answer (score 0):

An objectUrl is simply a link to the page that contains your object definition.

you can refer to creating object section from [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/)

You will also need to configure your namespace, action, object and story in your app management